# How can I know if Caps Lock is on in Dev-C++?

Tags: dev-c++

in first place, I´m sorry for my English.  The point is that I try to do a KeyLogger in dev-c++ for the school and I wanna know if there is a way to know if Caps Lock is on or off.  I don´t want it to recognize the key(if its pressed or not), I just wanna know if its on or not. Regards to everybody.  I´m using Dev-C++ 5.11

Comment: Have you tried searching here or Google?

Comment: Yes, I continued looking for a answer, finally I ve got it.

Answer (score 0):

The code is:

if ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001)!=0)

//Code when its On

else

//Code When its Off